# Problems with slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

First of all I'm a designer not a programmer, so treat me as a moron because I don't understand php, or javascript I just cbble websites together in dreamweaver!

Bascally on this page http://www.purbecks.com/revised_site_php/propertypage.php?prop=449 I have a slideshow, which has been working fine, until I tried to upload it last night, the slideshow has been constructed as an unordered list (I think) and now it’s not working as you’ll see if you look at the page.

Unfortunately the guy who did this seems t be uncontactable, so I need some help please.

Whatever the problem is, it s also stopping the main side show from working as well, so I am at a loss!

The code for the main slideshow:

```
<?php if($prop_is_top == 'yes') { ?>
<img style="position:absolute;z-index:1;opacity:0.9" src="../images/uo-large.png" width="475" height="359" alt=""> 
<?php } ?>
<ul id="gallery">
<?php for($i=1; $i<9; $i++) { ?>
<?php if(!empty($data["prop_img".$i])) { ?>
<li><img src="../images/<? print $data["prop_img".$i]; ?>" width="480" height="359" id="swapthis_<?php echo $i ?>"></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<div id="gallery-navigation">&nbsp;<span class="progress"></span>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clearboth">
```

For the thumbnails:
    
    
    " href="">" width="480" height="359" id="swapthis_">

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Phil

Comment: Is there any Javascript

Comment: You could also just recreate on there are many sources online to find a simple slider, here is a codepen example http://codepen.io/tunguska/pen/jEeyKa

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the page you mentioned and it is not getting the slider css and js files that you are trying to use on that page.The code is searching for css and js files at path below:

1. revised_site_php/scripts-ll/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css
2. revised_site_php/scripts-ll/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js

check if the files are there and if not place them there.

Comment: Thank you! The files had had gone missing from the server, so a big thanks for solvng that one one for me1

Comment: Thats great, thank you it solved the problem for me, for which I am very gratefull!

Comment: @PhilipLing welcome to SO, if you think shine answer your question, please accept it as an answer clicking on the left. Thanks!